# how to format read only pendrive

Tags: ubuntu, formatting

My Pendrive is of read only format

No delete file option is enabled

I tried GParted the format to option is disabled

Kindly give me some effective command line to format my pendrive

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If a filesystem has been mounted read-only, chmod will not help as it has a write operation as well. In that case,

Try remounting it read-write:

`sudo mount -o remount,rw '/media/USB'`

If the device has a write lock, we need to turn it off. Hardware locks cannot be disabled by software.

For NTFS based FS, ensure to use the ntfs-3g driver which should be selected by itself. Alternatively, this could help you!

`sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o uid=$(id -u) /dev/sdc /media/usb`

Answer (score 0):

**To fix USB pen drive read only in Ubuntu,follow the given below steps**

Step 1: Attach USB pen drive in system’s USB port. Automatically the Ubuntu will mount the USB pen drive and show icon on Desktop or Menu bar.

Open the terminal and become super user by running below given command

```
sudo su -
```

**Step 2:** First we have to find out in which directory the USB pen drive has been automatically mounted.For this run the **df -Th** command.
In given below output you can see,in my system the USB pen drive is mounted in **/media/linux/C38C-099C** ,partition is **/dev/sdd1** and filesystem is vfat.

**Note:** When you run df -Th command in your system,the USB pen drive may mount in different directory and the partition might also be different.Hence the output value which you will get, use the same values in further steps.

```
root@tuxworld:~# df -Th
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5      ext4       28G   25G  1.3G  96% /
udev           devtmpfs  2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     796M  1.1M  795M   1% /run
none           tmpfs     5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none           tmpfs     2.0G  528K  2.0G   1% /run/shm
none           tmpfs     100M  104K  100M   1% /run/user
cgroup         tmpfs     2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda7      ext4      9.2G  8.2G  539M  94% /partition7
/dev/sda8      ext3       46G   38G  6.2G  86% /partition8
/dev/sda9      ext3       74G   67G  3.1G  96% /partition9
/dev/sda21     ext4       14G  4.9G  8.3G  37% /partition10
/dev/sdd1      vfat       15G   12G  3.6G  77% /media/linux/C38C-099C
```

**Step 2:** Now unmount the directory in which the USB pen drive is automatically mounted . (As you can see mounted directory path in above ‘Step 1’)

**Note:** Replace the**/media/linux/C38C-099C** with the mounted USB pen drive directory path which is showing output in your system after running **df -Th** command.

```
umount /media/linux/C38C-099C
```

**Step 3:** As we know the USB pen drive got /dev/sdd1 partition
and filesystem is vfat(see in Step 1). Now we will run dosfsck command to check and repair the filesystem

**Note:** The dosfsck command check and repair MS-DOS filesystems.Because the filesystem of USB pen drive is vfat hence we are using this command

```
dosfsck -a /dev/sdd1
```

**Step 4:** After the dosfsck command get completed.Remove the USB pen drive from system and then re-attach back to system.Now your USB pen drive should working and it should not have read only filesystem.

**Note** After mounting the USB pen drive you may see a new file with extension .REC which was created because of **dosfsck** command.

**Step 5** Reboot the system after completing all the steps.

Reference : http://sharadchhetri.com/2013/12/19/how-to-fix-read-only-usb-pen-drive-in-ubuntu/